# Is there a launcher that features tab-completion?

Tags: software-rec, desktop-environment

I'm looking for a "proper" launcher that also allows running raw commands, including tab completion. Hence, it must do two things, at a minimum.

1. It's a "proper" launcher, hence respect `~/.local/share/applications/*.desktop`, not just commands in `$PATH`.
2. Run raw commands with tab completion, so I can type in `gimp /tmp/foo` <kbd>Tab</kbd> and have it autocomplete to `gimp /tmp/foobar.png`

### What I've tried

KDE's `krunner` is quite good, but doesn't offer tab completion of paths. `gmrun` and `grun` don't respect *.desktop files, and the latter also doesn't offer tab completion of paths. `kupfer` doesn't run raw commands at all, as far as I can tell.

(FWIW I'm running KDE, but hopefully this is not important.)

Comment: @mikeserv I'm not sure if we're talking about the same thing? Isn't `dmenu` a GUI for picking from a list of user-supplied items? i.e. similar to `zenity` or `yad`?

Comment: @mikeserv But I'd basically have to write it myself (using `dmenu` as a backbone), if I want it to execute what I enter, respect *.desktop files, and tab-complete for paths. I did install it, but it doesn't appear to offer any of that functionality out of the box.

Comment: @mikeserv Ahhh okay. I had just installed `dmenu` and read the man page, which didn't really suggest anything about it having launcher functionality. However, I've now tested both `dmenu` and `dmenu-file-completion`, and neither features tab completion of paths, nor reading *.desktop files. Thanks for the suggestion anyway.

Comment: How about [INTERROBANG](https://github.com/TrilbyWhite/interrobang)?

Comment: @Proletariat Thanks for the link. It looks interesting, but it doesn't seem to respect `~/.local/share/applications/*.desktop` files (I tried typing the `Name`). Also, it steal all keyboard input (can't type in another window), and doesn't seem to remember history, which makes my current solution (`gmrun`) better for the moment.

Comment: we discussed that feature for shellex here: https://github.com/Merovius/shellex/issues/5 . that said shellex also doesn't have that feature. did you check i3-dmenu-desktop?

Comment: @pseyfert No, I hadn't, but [this page](http://build.i3wm.org/docs/i3-dmenu-desktop.html) suggests that it *doesn't* run commands in `$PATH` as a feature. I also just found [j4-dmenu-desktop](https://github.com/enkore/j4-dmenu-desktop), which looks pretty cool, but doesn't offer tab completion.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [Rofi](https://davedavenport.github.io/rofi/) as far as I know it's capable of all your conditions hassle free and out of the box.  There is one exception and that is auto completion of the path (not command) which is hard to implement. However you can use Rofi with [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) (or alike).

here is pretty handy configuration for your setup ($HOME/rofi/config):

```
!=======================================
!=============  rofi  ==================
!=======================================

!| you can refer rofi site/screenshot for different configurations
rofi.location:          6
rofi.color-enabled:     true
rofi.color-window:      argb:ee0F3B5F, #CC9752, #CC9752
rofi.color-normal:      argb:00111111, #E5DBCF, argb:00111111, #CC9752, #0F3B5F
rofi.color-urgent:      argb:00111111, #af652f, argb:00111111, #af652f, #0F3B5F
rofi.color-active:      argb:00111111, #70a16c, argb:00111111, #70a16c, #0F3B5F
rofi.key-combi:         Alt-F3
rofi.separator-style:   dash
rofi.fullscreen:        false
rofi.padding:           2
rofi.hide-scrollbar:    true
rofi.line-margin:       5
rofi.fake-transparency: true
rofi.yoffset:           -20
rofi.xoffset:           0
rofi.width:             80
rofi.lines:         4
rofi.terminal:      urxvt
rofi.font:      Inconsolata 18
rofi.fuzzy:         true
rofi.run-command:   zsh -c "{cmd}"
rofi.opacity:       75
```

p.s. pay attention to `rofi.run-command` and `rofi-terminal`.